# Error compiling template while trying to make email links in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am working on a small application that displays a "users" JSON in an *HTML5 table*. It uses **Bootstrap 3** and **Vue**.

The code I have so far:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      users: null,
      loading: true,
      errored: false
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    axios
      .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then(response => {
        this.users = response.data
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        this.errored = true
      })
      .finally(() => this.loading = false)
  }
});

Vue.filter('lowercase', function (value) {
  return value.toLowerCase();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.18.0/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app" class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-default table-container">
    <div class="panel-heading">Users</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="dataTable">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>City</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr v-for="(user, index) in users">
            <td>{{index + 1}}</td>
            <td>{{user.name}}</td>
            <td>{{user.email | lowercase}}</td>
            <td>{{user.address.city}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to turn the email addresses in the table into email links: `<a :href="mailto:user.email | lowercase">{{user.email | lowercase}}`.

The line above results in an *Error compiling template* and *prevents the rendering* of the table (even though `<a :href="user.email | lowercase">{{user.email | lowercase}}`does alow rendering.

Where am I wrong? What is a viable solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up the `mailto` inside a string with those email addresses.

Try this:

`<td><a :href="'mailto:' + user.email | lowercase">{{user.email | lowercase}}</a></td>`

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      users: null,
      loading: true,
      errored: false
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    axios
      .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then(response => {
        this.users = response.data
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        this.errored = true
      })
      .finally(() => this.loading = false)
  }
});

Vue.filter('lowercase', function (value) {
  return value.toLowerCase();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.18.0/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app" class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-default table-container">
    <div class="panel-heading">Users</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="dataTable">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>City</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr v-for="(user, index) in users">
            <td>{{index + 1}}</td>
            <td>{{user.name}}</td>
            <td><a :href="'mailto:' + user.email | lowercase">{{user.email | lowercase}}</a></td>
            <td>{{user.address.city}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the `| lowercase` pipe / filter requires one argument and you're attempting to add two strings together (`'mailto:' + user.email`) immediately before it.

Try replacing with either: `:href="('mailto:' + user.email) | lowercase"`

or making 'mailto:' + user.email a computed property

Comment: the parenthesis doesn't matter at all. what the OP missed is actually to wrap the `mailto` word in a string like this `'mailto'` and concatenate with the email address with a `+` operator